# 'SelectElement' does not contain a definition for 'SelectByText'

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ToolsQA
{
    class FirstTestCase
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(" http://toolsqa.wpengine.com/automation-practice-form/");
            IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("continents"));
            SelectElement dropdown = new SelectElement(element);
            dropdown.SelectByText("Europe");
       }
    }
}
```

This is mistake:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS1061  'SelectElement' does not contain a definition for
>   'SelectByText' and no extension method 'SelectByText' accepting a
>   first argument of type 'SelectElement' could be found (are you missing
>   a using directive or an assembly reference?)  ToolsQA

How does solve it?

Comment: Delete line  `dropdown.SelectByText("Europe");` could be the answer. But if you specify what you actually trying to achieve, we might help you some how.

Comment: Did you install the Selenium.Support package using NuGet?

Comment: As @JeffC said you either need to install or try reinstalling the Selenium Support package; I've had this problem before and it was solved by just reinstalling the package.